# Abbreviation for Ton

Tags: abbreviations, measuring-units

I went to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ton) looking for the symbol/abbreviation for ton. `t` would be ambiguous since there is both a `short ton` and a `long ton`, which mean two different weights.

I cannot find a standard abbreviation to eliminate this ambiguity. Granted, "ton", as a word, is so short you wouldn't need to abbreviate it. Yet, by itself, it is not clear to which type of ton you're referring.

I was able to find abbreviations for all other units except for short ton and long ton. I'm hoping someone here knows what the proper abbreviations are.

Comment: Both 'ton' and 't' are ambiguous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree.

Comment: I have seen (many years ago) claims that the short ton is "t" and the long ton is "T".

Answer (score 2):

Look here: https://www.weightconversions.org/abbreviations.htm

In the US:
The US customary ton (short ton) is abbreviated t or sh.tn. or sh.t.
The British imperial ton (long ton) is abbreviated l.tn. or l.t.
The metric ton (tonne) is abbreviated t or mt or MT

In most other countries:
The metric ton (tonne) is abbreviated t

Comment: The implication is that lines 2-5 are a faithful representation of the WeightConversions material, which they are not. In that article, 't' extends to both the US customary ton (short ton) and the British imperial ton (long ton). You haven't reproduced this, neither have you given justification for what you actually show.